Allowing ECR Credentials to persist inside Jenkins Docker Cloud configuration
I'm setting up a Docker Cloud (for dynamically assigning container agents) using the Docker plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/
Some of my images are saved on our AWS account's ECR, and I can't store persistent ECR credentials to fit this format, the Jenkins cloud configuration asks for -
I expected some workaround to exist, but instead I just simply can't pull images from ECR given I can't use anything like  docker.withRegistry Since we're talking about configuration and not something inside the pipeline code. Anyone encountered enything similar? Or got any ideas on how to deal with it?
Thanks!

"I can't store persistent ECR credentials to fit this format, the Jenkins cloud configuration asks for -" in what format are your credentials that Jenkins cannot store them?

I'm using the docker cloud plugin - Which requires a persistent set of cerdentials as part of Jenkins' credentials to be passed for the image templates as registry credetnials. This means that unless I want to manually generate a new token once every 8hrs, I won't be able to implement the dynamic ECR tokens.

Take a look at the aws-credentials plugin. It should be able to story any kind of AWS credentials and provide them for the registry auth.

Thank you, it ended up working! All I needed to do was to create a IAM execution role with the GetAuthorizationToken for "" and specific ecr: permissions for the desired repos, and applying a trust policy to allow my EC2 (acting as a docker host)'s IAM execution role to assume the role needed for interaction with ECR

Glad you've figured it out!
